# How to hide a NSMenuItem?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsmenuitem

I'm currently writing a Mac App in Objective-C and can't for the life of me figure out how to hide a NSMenuItem. (Note: Yes I really mean hide, not disable/grey-out.  I realize the UX implications of doing so, but the functionality isn't really what you think it is.  Just trust me on this.)

The documentation doesn't mention anyway to do so, is it even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have defined your `NSMenuItem` in your header and connected it through your NIB, you can simply call the **Hidden** property.

```
[myMenuItem setHidden:YES];
```

"Greying out" the menuItem would be `[myMenuItem setEnabled: NO];`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the function may have changed to

```
[menuItem isHidden: YES]
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenuitem

Comment: isHidden is a getter, not a setter. You can't change it.

Comment: In Swift 4.0, `menuItem.isHidden = true` works. You can try it if you don't believe me. I assumed the API is the same for Obj C. Maybe not?

Comment: That's only the Swift name-convention. The Cocoa Obj-C property is called "hidden". the property-accessor synthesizers for Obj-C would create for you 2 getters: "isHidden" and "hidden" and a setter "setHidden". So - using the dot notation in Obj-C you can only do X.hidden = YES/NO;  or [X setHidden:YES/NO];

Answer (score 0):

The Obj-C property is named "hidden". This means, the underlying boolean member is named _hidden, and 3 accessors are automatically synthesized for you: 2 getters: `isHidden` and `hidden` plus one setter: `setHidden`.

In Obj-C, using dot notation you can only set the property using:

```
myMenuItem.hidden = YES; // or NO
```

or in normal message:

```
[myMenuItem setHidden:YES]; // or NO
```

to get the value you can either `myMenuItem.hidden`, `myMenuItem.isHidden`, `[myMenuItem hidden]` or `[myMenuItem setHidden]`

Now Swift borrows its naming convention from the (lingually inferior in my opinion) C and C++. A boolean property will have both its setter and getter named "isHidden".

When Xcode converts the Cocoa Obj-C Framework headers with the Obj-C interface defining the property hidden --- it synthesizes an "isHidden" swift property which is read/write.

That's why you can use both as getter and setter:

```
if myMenuItem.isHidden {
}
```

and

```
myMenuItem.isHidden = true // or false
```

Hope this covers the issue